Vuetify v-datable expanded with different api
I need to create an accordion effect data table similar to this code pen
'''https://codepen.io/maycevara/pen/RwPvQew'''
but I need to fetch different data every time I expand a level and I need to use recursive component.

surely there's a click or expand event you can listen to to fetch data... "and I need to use recursive component."  why?  I wouldn't use recursion unless for good reason, and you've not explained why or shown any attempt of your own using recursion that could provide context for what you're asking (stackoverflow isn't a code writing service).  see How to Ask

I do understand that Stack overflow is not a code writing service , I am using the same code pen I provided. My question instead of repeatedly creating a data table every time I expand a row can I create a component and call it when I expand  with different key. I am not sure how to do it that's why I didn't provide a code different then the code pen
